# Default value for UITableView Cell if Firebase snapshot is nil

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have looked around and I cannot figure this out.

I am trying to set **a default value** of a tableView Cell if a Firebase snapshot returns **nil**

**Example:**

A snapshot is made to show all the event names from my Firebase Database
in a tableView using a dequeReusableCell.

But if the snapshot **returns nil**, the tableView returns with 1 cell with a label saying "*Sorry, there are no events.*"

---

---

Here is my firebase snapshot code. This code does currently handle if the snapshot does return nil with a **print()** statement.

```
func populateTableView(){
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("events").child(uid!).child(currentDate).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            self.events = []
            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshot {
                    //print("SNAP: \(snap)")
                    if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let key = snap.key
                        let event = Event(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                        self.events.append(event)
                        //print(self.events)
                    }
                }

            }

            if !snapshot.exists() {

                self.eventStatus = false
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                print("No Event here")

            } else {

                self.eventStatus = true
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        })

    }
```

---

The firebase Objects get stored into the Event class and are stored a dictionary. I don't think this code is needed, but here is the event class code for more context.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class Event {

    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    private var _description: String!
    private var _imageUrl: String!
    private var _eventTitle: String!
    private var _eventType: String!
    private var _eventTime: String!
    private var _eventStartDate: String!
    private var _eventEndDate: String!
    private var _monthlyRepeat: String!
    private var _weeklyRepeat: String!
    private var _eventColor: String!

    private var _postKey: String!
    private var _postRef: DatabaseReference!

    var description: String {
        return _description
    }

    var imageUrl: String {
        return _imageUrl
    }

    var eventTitle: String {
        return _eventTitle
    }

    var eventType: String {
        return _eventType
    }

    var eventTime: String {
        return _eventTime
    }

    var eventStartDate: String {
        return _eventStartDate
    }

    var eventEndDate: String {
        return _eventEndDate
    }

    var monthlyRepeat: String {
        return _monthlyRepeat
    }

    var weeklyRepeat: String {
        return _weeklyRepeat
    }

    var eventColor: String {
        return _eventColor
    }

    var postKey: String {
        return _postKey
    }



    init(postKey: String, postData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        self._postKey = postKey

        if let description = postData["description"] as? String {
            self._description = description
        }

        if let imageUrl = postData["event_Image_URL"] as? String {
            self._imageUrl = imageUrl
        }

        if let eventTitle = postData["event_Title"] as? String {
            self._eventTitle = eventTitle
        }

        if let eventType = postData["event_Type"] as? String {
            self._eventType = eventType
        }

        if let eventTime = postData["event_Time"] as? String {
            self._eventTime = eventTime
        }

        if let eventStartDate = postData["start_Date"] as? String {
            self._eventStartDate = eventStartDate
        }

        if let eventEndDate = postData["end_Date"] as? String {
            self._eventEndDate = eventEndDate
        }

        if let monthlyRepeat = postData["monthly_Repeat"] as? String {
            self._monthlyRepeat = monthlyRepeat
        }

        if let weeklyRepeat = postData["weekly_Repeat"] as? String {
            self._weeklyRepeat = weeklyRepeat
        }

        if let eventColor = postData["color"] as? String {
            self._eventColor = eventColor
        }

        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let eventRef = ref.child("events").child(uid!).child("Monday May, 29")


        _postRef = eventRef.child(_postKey)

    }



}
```

Comment: Did I understand your question. You are looking for help on how to populate your tableview?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for a way to show a certain cell if a Firebase Snapshot is returned nil or does not exist.

Comment: Maybe the answer I just entered will get you of to a start. I have not tested the code so - try if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this is to add a title `UILabel` to your `ViewcController` and change the text when snapshot is not available.

Or if that doesn't work for you for some reason you could try this:

I did not check this, but I might get you on track.

First you will need to change your `populateTableView` method so that an `events` array is created even when snapshot has no results. This way the `events` array count will be 1 (and one row will be added to your `tableView`) even if snapshot had no result.

```
populateTableView(){
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("events").child(uid!).child(currentDate).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.events = []
        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {
                //print("SNAP: \(snap)")
                if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let key = snap.key
                    let event = Event(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                    self.events.append(event)
                    //print(self.events)
                }
            }
        }
        else{ // Snapshot does not exist
            let postDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>  // Add an empty Dictionary
            let key = -1 // Or what ever value you could not possibly expect
            let event = Event(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
            self.events.append(event)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("No Event here")
        }
    })
}
```

Notice that when snapshot is not valid or available you add an empty `Dictionary` with an unique `key` value to your `events` array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return events.count
}
```

You need to create two custom cells with unique identifiers.

Now you can "actually" populate your `tableView` similar to this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let event = events.[indexPath.row]
    let conditionKey = event.key
    if(conditionKey == -1){ // or whatever value you gave in populateTableView to indicate that snapshot did not exist
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifierCellNotSoGood", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellNotSoGood
        cell.noSnapShotLabel1.text = "Sorry, there are no events."
        return cell
    }
    else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifierCellAllGood", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellAllGood
        cell.yourCustomLabel1.text = event.key      // Or whatever data you are displaying 
        cell.sourCustomLabel2.text = event.event    // Or whatever data you are displaying 
        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell
}
```

If you need to handle the selection of a table cell you can do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // get rid of the ugly highlighting
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

    let event = events.[indexPath.row
    let conditionKey = event.key
    if(conditionKey == -1){ // or whatever value you gave in populateTableView to indicate that snapshot did not exist
        // Do what you need or not
    }
    else{
        // Do something meaningful with your database
        doSomething(withEventData: event)
    }
}
```